# Insteate custom OAuth2User in spring-security-oauth2 causes deserialize error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I’m using spring-security-oauth2-client in my web application. I want to use custom user type. But got error when Insteate OAuthUser using request body that authentication server sent.

The reason why I use custom user type is because I want to use string value inside of hashmap as nameAttributeKey instead of string value.

**SecurityConfig**

```
    http.oauth2Login()
      .userInfoEndpoint()
        .customUserType(NaverOAuth2User.class, "naver");
```

**NaverOAuth2User**

```
public class NaverOAuth2User implements OAuth2User {

   public NaverOAuth2User(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, Map<String, Object> attributes, String nameAttributeKey) {
           ...
   }

   ...

}
```

I expect NaverOAuth2User's constructor called, but error caused before serialization.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.rw.springsecurity.vo.NaverOAuth2User` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar:2.9.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1452) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar:2.9.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1028) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar:2.9.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar:2.9.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar:2.9.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar:2.9.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4014) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar:2.9.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3085) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.9.3.jar:2.9.9.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
```

I assume that constructor parameter is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes Spring Security uses `RestTemplate` to deserialize data coming from userInfo endpoint into the custom type we specify which **needs to have default constructor**.

You can check this logic in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.CustomUserTypesOAuth2UserService`.